# Can patients receive SHINGRIX together with TWINRIX or AREXVY?

Tags: side-effects, drug-interactions, vaccine

Can patients receive SHINGRIX (Recombinant Adjuvanted Zoster Vaccine) together with other vaccines? Specifically either:

- TWINRIX (Hepatitis A & Hepatitis B Recombinant Vaccine)
- AREXVY (Respiratory syncytial virus (RSV) vaccine)

Is there increased risk for severe side effects in either case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The US Centers for Disease Control has [a page which discusses simultaneous administration of SHINGRIX with other vaccines](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/vpd/shingles/hcp/shingrix/administering-vaccine.html):

> **CDC general recommendations advise that recombinant and adjuvanted vaccines, such as Shingrix, can be administered concomitantly, at different anatomic sites, with other adult vaccines**, including COVID-19 vaccines. Concomitant administration of Shingrix with Fluarix Quadrivalent (influenza vaccine, QIV), 23-valent pneumococcal polysaccharide vaccine (Pneumovax23, PPSV23) and Tetanus Toxoid, Reduced Diphtheria Toxoid and Acellular Pertussis Vaccine, Adsorbed (Boostrix) has been studied, and there was no evidence for interference in the immune response to either vaccine or safety concerns. Coadministration of Shingrix with adjuvanted influenza vaccine (Fluad) and COVID-19 vaccines is being studied. [Emphasis added]

Since both Twinrix and Arexvy are adult recommended recombinant and adjuvanted vaccines, we can conclude that general recommendations advise they can be administered at the same time, but at different sites.

However, from the CDC page, we can also surmise that no studies are available specifically for Twinrix or Arexvy. The information provided by GSK (the manufacturer of both vaccines) says as much:

The [package insert for Twinrix](https://gskpro.com/content/dam/global/hcpportal/en_US/Prescribing_Information/Twinrix/pdf/TWINRIX.PDF) notes:

> There are no data to assess the concomitant use of TWINRIX with other vaccines

Meanwhile, the [package insert for Arexvy](https://ca.gsk.com/media/6988/arexvy.pdf) notes:

> Concomitant administration of AREXVY with other vaccines are unknown.

Thus, the CDC generally recommends that all recombinant and adjuvanted vaccines can be administered together. There is no information to suggest and increased risk of adverse events, but there have been no specific studies to detect them other than the [Vaccine Adverse Event Reporting System](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccinesafety/ensuringsafety/monitoring/vaers/index.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanations!